java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC and No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:
im trying to create/use an SQLite database with java using the code below, but it gives me an error, and ive been scouring the internet for the fix of this problem for two days but i still havent found a solution for my problem.
all the other questions just like this also don't have a correct working answer, none of them work for me
im using jdk 1.8.0_202 and intellij ideaU 2023.2.6
this is all the code:
package com.example.JavaQuiz;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:./databases/piko.sqlite";

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url)) {
            if (conn != null) {
                System.out.println("Connected to SQLite database.");
            } else {
                System.err.println("Failed to connect to SQLite database.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error creating SQLite database: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

and this is the full error:
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -jar C:\Projects\Java\JavaQuiz\out\artifacts\JavaQuiz_jar\JavaQuiz.jar
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.example.JavaQuiz.Program.main(Program.java:11)
Error creating SQLite database: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:./databases/piko.sqlite

Process finished with exit code 0

and these are my project settings screenshots: screenshots
I've tried this tutorial but theyre all the same and their same approach gives me the same above error, however ive tried and failed to correctly use i think this usage tutorial in the jdbc github page screenshot, https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc
my main goal was to create a sqlite database using this tutorial, but to do that you have to set up the jdbc which in my case it can't find it, and i know that in eclipse it seems much easier and straightforward but im later going to use android studio and android studio works just like intellij idea so i have to learn it, so using eclipse is not an option for me. please someone help, any help will be appreciated

Since your full command line is shown, unless file C:\Projects\Java\JavaQuiz\out\artifacts\JavaQuiz_jar\JavaQuiz.jar is a 'fat jar' containing the driver (which it isn't, as there's a CNF exception) that would be the only way that command could succeed. Remedy - make sure the sqlite driver jar is in the classpath

Does the manifest in the JAR have a Class-Path attribute, and does it reference the SQLite library? And if so, does that library exist in the referenced location?

The scenario @MarkRotteveel mentions would allow that command to work actually, were it in place and all correct, though I think it's not that frequently seen anymore
